# How to use custom package with glide

Tags: go, glide-golang

I use golang Masterminds/glide to manage package. here is my project:

```
$GOPATH/    
      bin/  
      pkg/
      src/
         go_test/
            long(own custom package: just print a "hello")  
            main.go  
            glide.yaml  
            vendor/  
                github.com/lib/pq
```

the long package is used in main.go like :

```
 package main 
   import(
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/lib/pq"
    "long"
  )
  func main(
    ...
  }
```

the glide.yaml is:

```
package:  go_test
import:   
- package: github.com/lib/pq
```

when go run main.go  the error is: can not found package long .
if I put the long package into the vendor/ and then **glide up**
 it will show can not detect vcs about the "long" dependencies. but can run with project.
 so  I want to know how to set that glide will skip the long package detect and the project can run .

note: I use the ignore: in the yaml. if add long to ignore .the project will can run because can't find long package.

Comment: Can you show the line where you do import of your `long` package? Is it looks like `import "go_test/long"`?

Comment: in the main.go file.

Comment: as above you see ,  in the main.go file ,  if put in vendor , it can run . but the glide will say can not detect vcs about long package.

Comment: So you should use `"go_test/long"` instead on just `"long"`

Comment: And it must not be in your vendor directory

Comment: ye,  when I add "go_test/long" and it can find the path of long package. even  when I execute  **glide up** .  very thanks. and please  write as a answer that  I can  select as correct answer.  thanks again

Comment: You are welcome @Long!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the correct package name is a full path starting from `/src` directory in you project you should use `"go_test/long"` instead on just `"long"` in you `import` statement. And because it is your own code and not a vendor dependency it must not be under `vendor` directory.

Comment: very complete instruction!